# JavaScript alert when a Window is closed

Tags: javascript

I want to have a JavaScript alert when a window is closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function popup (url) {
      fenster = window.open(url, "Popupfenster", "width=500,height=300,resizable=yes");
      fenster.focus();
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

I use this code to open the window but how can I have a JavaScript alert that popup when the window is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onbeforeunload`:

```
fenster.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert('Window closed');
    return null;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for this noob question but how can I make it running I mean where I have to put the code?